# How to establish connection between oracle database and intellij-idea

Tags: intellij-idea, oracle12c

You can see there is no option and I have already tried:

[image: you can see there is no option and I have already tried]

Comment: To bypass Ultimate, you can us Oracles Client ODBC driver, it's slower but works.

Answer (score 1):

[This feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/relational-databases.html) is available only in IntelliJ IDEA **Ultimate**, see [the editions comparison](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

According to the icon on your screenshot, you are running IntelliJ IDEA **Community**.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Database Navigator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator) plugin.